# RxJava search for item in list

Tags: rx-java, observable

I'm trying to turn this into an Observable without having an external variable or extra classes. Is this possible? It's a basic search through a list:

```
    //...
    for(int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
        if(items.get(i).id == findId) return i;
    }
    return -1;
```

So basically I have a string id which if I find I'd like to return the item index in the "items" list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One "neat" way of doing this without additional traverses overhead is as follows:

```
  Observable<Integer> index = Observable.from(items)
            .takeWhile(item -> item.id != findId)
            .count()
            .map(count -> count == data.size() ? -1 : count);
```

But i would stick to non-Rx approach for such simple use cases

Answer (score 1):

One way to go is to use `fromCallable` method to create an `Observable`:

```
Observable.fromCallable(() -> {
            for(int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
                if(items.get(i).id == findId) return i;
            }
            return -1;
        });
```

or more declarative approach:

```
Observable.from(items)
                .filter(item -> item.id == findId)
                .map(items::indexOf);
```

Comment: How can you throw an error, return an error code or return null if the item is not found in the second (declarative) approach?

Comment: Observable.from(items)
                .filter(item -> item.id == findId)
                .toList()
                .map(filteredItems -> {
                    if (filteredItems.isEmpty()) return -1;
                    else return items.indexOf(filteredItems.get(0));
                });

Answer (score 1):

I am aware that this is an old question, but maybe someone will come in handy my solution using a [helper class](https://github.com/il4enkodev/RxSandbox/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/il4enkodev/sandbox/rx/util/IndexedValue.java). It's a much more flexible, consistent and declarative way to do so. Any finite Observables are supported. Example:

```
Single<Integer> result = Observable.fromIterable(items)
            .as(IndexedValue.firstMatch(next -> next.id == findId))
            .map(IndexedValue::index)
            .toSingle(-1);
```